# Compile JDK8 error.''Could not find freetype''

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java-8

I am compiling JDK8 at Ubuntu 16.04 LTS,(Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-91-generic x86_64)),there is a error make me Confused，when i do`./bash configure`,the error is

> configure: error: Could not find freetype! You might be able to fix this by running 'sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev'. 
>   configure exiting with result code 1

but when i do the `sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev`,ubuntu tell freetype is already installed like this

```
ubuntu@VM-137-125-ubuntu:~/openjdk$ sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libfreetype6-dev is already the newest version (2.6.1-0.1ubuntu2.3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 225 not upgraded.
```

Comment: All seems right there, so next would be to ask the simpler questions like, are you sure your terminal window is open to the same server with the problem?  And maybe you just need to re-launch the terminal window because some environment variables are not set in the current window.

Comment: This looks more like a question for https://superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/build-dev/2014-October/013491.html), you need something like this:

```
./configure --with-freetype-include=/usr/include/freetype2 --with-freetype-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Answer (score 0):

Even much simpler, this also works:

```
/configure --with-freetype=/usr
```